# Yum Lock on AWS Linux t2.micro

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am receiving a yum lock error each time I attempt to run  yum update -y on an AWS Linux t2 micro.  I have attempted to kill the process PID # associated with the yum update -y process but have not been able to resolve the lock.

I have terminated and created a new AWS Linux t2 micro, and obtain the same error with the new instance.

I have been working on this issue for 2 days now.

Has anyone encountered this error and how did you resolve it?

Thank you for any guidance/help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using `yum-cron` service, but we need more details to confirm.

Could you please give us more details about what is locking your yum process with something like, that will tell you what is using yum that is preventing you to use it:

```
[root-pts1@centos7 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 2064.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  45 M RSS (917 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sun Oct 10 20:57:28 2021 - 00:05 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 2064

[root-pts2@centos7 ~]# ps -fp 2064
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2064  1248 42 20:57 pts/0    00:00:05 /usr/bin/python /bin/yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has occurred again.  So, this issue is not resolved.  I launched a t2 micro aws linux instance and am encountering the yum lock again.

I will create a new issue and post details of the lock.

---

Apparently, this was an issue on the AWS side.  The locks were apparently resolved by AWS and I was able to run yum without any issues.

Thanks for the reply Reynaldo.